# Chat Bot Using RASA NLU

Tags: python, chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa

i am trying to create a chat bot using RASA NLU

my nlu_model.py

```
from rasa_nlu.training_data import load_data
from rasa_nlu.config import RasaNLUModelConfig
from rasa_nlu.model import Trainer


def train_nlu(data, config, model_dir):
    training_data = load_data(data)
    trainer = Trainer(RasaNLUModelConfig(config))
    trainer.train(training_data)
    model_directory = trainer.persist(model_dir, fixed_model_name='weathernlu')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    train_nlu('./data/data.json', 'config_spacy.json', './models/nlu')
```

while executing the command 'python nlu_model.py'
showing error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nlu_model.py", line 14, in <module>
    train_nlu('./data/data.json', 'config_spacy.json', './models/nlu')
  File "nlu_model.py", line 8, in train_nlu
    trainer = Trainer(RasaNLUModelConfig(config))
  File "D:\Face Detection\Rasa-Nlu-Test\env\lib\site-packages\rasa_nlu\config.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.override(configuration_values)
  File "D:\Face Detection\Rasa-Nlu-Test\env\lib\site-packages\rasa_nlu\config.py", line 186, in override
    self.__dict__.update(config)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

how its showing like this..

1. How can i solve this
2. can any one share any good link for creating chat bot using rasa nlu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rasa NLU was deprecated 1.5 years ago in favor of https://github.com/rasahq/rasa . I highly recommend you to switch to the maintained version as you will an up to date documentation and lot of new features which make it easier to interact with it.